# Tools for Monitoring Restful Services

Tags: .net, monitoring, microservices, restful-architecture

When coming to monitoring synchronous restful APIs that are initially developed using .net core, what are the best recommended tools that might have any of:

- Performance Monitoring
- Service Health checks
- Logging
- Tracing
- Dashboards

I would be interested with any open source platform tools if available that can monitor APIs not running in containerized environments.

Answer (score 1):

We're using [Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus) + [Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/WINDOWS_SERVICE.md) + [Grafana](https://grafana.com/): a solution designed to collect metrics from applications and offers alerting and graphs (with Grafana). Very happy with it: its open-source, resilient and built for scale.

I see there's an [open-source Prometheus client for .net](https://github.com/andrasm/prometheus-net), although you could just use Telegraf to expose your metrics if that was not available.

Answer (score 0):

The **performance monitoring, service health-check and the dashboards** can be done via Consul. The service discovery is awesome and will cater quite nicely to your APIs.

Check out their software comparisons page here:

https://www.consul.io/intro/vs/index.html

When it comes to **log aggregation and stack tracing**, I personally would use [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/) or [Retrace](https://stackify.com/) but as you're looking for open source I would go for [GrayLog](https://www.graylog.org/).